# Add remote with ssh protocol and key - how to troubleshoot issue?

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to add a remote address to a branch, but when trying to fetch, or do `git ls-remote` , I get Permission denied:

```
myuser@22.22.22.222: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

So I'm wondering how to troubleshoot this?
I tried using regular command line and Git bash.

It worked when I tried a different repo and server, connecting with root user in the same way:

```
git remote add prod ssh://root@11.111.11.11:22/myfolder/gittest.git
```

The successful message is:  `From ssh://root@22.222.22.22:22/myfolder/gittest.git`

On the problematic server the user has access and I can ssh with no problem , I specify a key at the same time:

```
ssh -i .ssh/mykey.pem myuser@22.22.22.222
```

When I try to add the remote to the server, I do this:

```
git remote add prod ssh://myuser@22.222.22.22:22/myfolder/gittest.git
```

But it needs the `.pem` file , so I've specified it in `.ssh/config`:

```
Host theserver
 HostName 22.22.22.222
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myfile.pem
 Port 22
```

How can I verify that the `.pem` file being read? If I remove the text from `config`, there is no error about "missing key" or anything?

The folder exists on the server: `/myfolder/gittest.git` (myfolder is at the root).
I also tried to a differemt location for the repo, moving it into a sub directory to the user. But it's the same error.

So how can I pinpoint the problem?

If it's of any use, when I check the user on the server: `id myuser` I get:

```
uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),
25(floppy),27(sudo),
29(audio),30(dip),33(www-data),44(video),46(plugdev),119(netdev),120(lxd)
```

**Update:**

I updated the config , adding `User` and `IdentitiesOnly`, and changed the remote address to:

```
git remote add prod theserver:/myfolder/gittest.git
```

**Verify that config file is read**

If I remove the config file from `.ssh` folder and then do `git ls-remote` it says  `Could not resolve hostname theserver` , so that means that it is being found when it's in `.ssh`.

**Verify connection**

On my other *working* example, if I remove the key from .ssh folder and do `git ls-remote`, it says `The authenticity of host '11.111.11.11' can't be established.` (and so on) - so that seems to verify that I have established a connection but have not been authenticated.

But on the problem server, `git ls-remote` only gives:

```
ssh: connect to host 22.22.22.222 port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This is the same if I change the IP in config to something completely wrong.
So that would suggest that it's not related to the key? I'm not sure it connects to the IP correctly.
But I do get access using normal ssh.

**Update: Solved**

My odd case had to do with VPN. I had to activate the VPN because that's how the SSH and the server required.
Then it worked. (using this way of connecting with config: `git remote add prod theserver:/myfolder/gittest.git` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the (mostly) correct host alias set up in your configuration. Your URL just has to reference it. So define `theserver` as you are, but include the user name as well.

```
Host theserver
 User myuser
 HostName 22.22.22.222
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myfile.pem
 Port 22
```

Now configure `git` with

```
git remote add prod theserver:myfolder/gittest.git
```

When trying to connect to `theserver`, SSH will look for a `Host` entry with that name. What it *won't* do is take `ssh://myuser@22.222.22.22:22/myfolder/gittest.git` and look for a `Host` block with the same address.